# How to return type based on generic input type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm working on a wrapper for `fetch`. I'd like to create a generic function for all CRUD (post, get, update, delete) operations. The GET request returns some data wheres a DELETE request might not return any data.

```
function fetchIt<T>(path: string, init?: RequestInit | undefined): T {
  // really use fetch
  // ...
  // if T is not provided return null
  //
  // if T is given return a value of type T

  return {} as T
}

interface User {
  name: string
}

// getResult should be of type User because we provided User as input type
const getResult = fetchIt<User>('/users/1')

// deleteResult should be null because we did not provide any input type
const deleteResult = fetchIt('/users')
```

Here is link to the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAhAUxlAFgSRgHgBUA%20ACgAcBDGLALmQGcYAnOCAcwBpk24YB%20egCU0ARzBomOCH2QAfZJAAmaEGzRKAlPULIA3sGTIA9MeTM0lADZWAnooZpUGbIZNmAdF7enzGMMwoDAgAthhYbOzISMgA4gCiuhbikjA%20xul%20MAEoEGA20SgAIvEAMonxfilMwG4W2YH6AL7IlAzIhMBNtWwwaMwglFBOAKqOzPpuEJRh9EysHF21vuwYIgz5MIxYCPlKyABGTgggyDC25KPjh2hQlGCOyADuTuTMCABucCr7Y-2t7TY5DAW3Ol2AUCQTGQqxg602yAAvM5MLgCH9mGQAOTGB79BjGACMWM0yzMKisGDQ8KsWwYOz2N2QeQKRzueOeTiU32ZCC2b0%203yclAg9iBILOFzQEKhWwpVJpW2R6FReFIOLxzAYJKAA).

I don't want to return `T | null` because then I always have to check whether the result is null or not.

```
// this is not what I want
function fetchThis<T>(): T | null {
  return null
}

const a = fetchThis()
const b = fetchThis<User>()

if (b !== null) {
  console.log(b)
}
```

I'd like to get `null` whenever I don't provide a generic type and whenever I provide a type it should be the return value.

Any ideas? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want `T` itself to be `null` when it is not manually specified by the caller.  If so, you can use a [*generic parameter default*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) with the `=` syntax:

```
function fetchIt<T = null>(path: string, init?: RequestInit | undefined): T {
  return {} as T; // unsafe assertion, but so is fetch() I guess so ‍♂️
}
```

This gives you the behavior you're asking for:

```
const getResult = fetchIt<User>('/users/1');
// const getResult: User
const deleteResult = fetchIt('/users');
// const deleteResult: null
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAplCALAklAPAFUQF5EwQAbcgPgAoAHAQygwC5EBnKAJxjAHMANIl4woAfjYAlFAEcQKTljCjEAH0TgAJimC8UmgJRtCAbwBQiRFzQguSEwF9EDdonwBuMw7NneUFFzADBAoiACq7AGI5pZgDAC2KGycPPxePhAInIh8aNLsFFDEyGiYOLgRAbQA5AD0IJFc7LUAjNUGnrW1iJlg2blQ+YVslVxmvdna5GgoQ+RFJKjo2FA0dQ0B7O2d3RNFUzNzUGxklEA)

Comment: I like that and I didn't know about generic parameter defaults. However TypeScript complains when I actually return `null`.

Comment: Just return `null as T` if you're going to return `null` ([example](https://tsplay.dev/N9JyMm)).  It might be possible to jump through hoops to have something that the compiler can be more safe with, but `fetch()` is completely type-unsafe and equivalent to a type assertion anyway so I don't see the point.  (e.g., if you call `fetchIt<A>("url")` and `fetchIt<B>("url")`, those are both just `fetchIt("url")` at runtime, so `A` and `B` are just assertions which might be wrong).

Comment: I understand your example but I cannot return `null` directly ([example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAplCALAklAPAFUQF5EwQAbcgPgAoAHAQygwC5EBnKAJxjAHMANIl4woAfjYAlFAEcQKTljCjEAH0TgAJimC8UmgJRtCAbwBQiRAHoriLmhBckNALJMMAOi4MwmuAFsaA0RcRAAGDwBWRDFEEwBfRDYySmCGdkR8AG4LOwcnUgpyHPizM14oFC5gBggURABVdiq43LAGfxQ2Th5+M1KzCARORD40aXYKKGJkNEwcXCaq2gByKxBmrnYrAEYVgxybRCGwEbGoCam2Ja5B4entcjQUS-JpklR0bCgaNY2q9j7Q62E4jR7PV5QZJFIA)). Do I have to do something like `return null as unknown as T`?

Comment: Yes, you can write `null as unknown as T`.  The compiler tries to warn about assertions if the two types don't look "related enough", but this is a heuristic, and you can deal with it by an intermediate type like `unknown` or `any` or `null | T` that the compiler sees as being related to both `null` and `T`.